# I need to remove folder and any descendents

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

I install centos in container and I must delete a folder so I run:

```
sudo docker run -it centos /bin/bash
```

and in this particular folder there are two other folder nodebb and nodebb1. I want delete nodebb1 and all files and directorie so I do :

```
rm -r nodebb1
```

and I obtain :

```
rm: remove regular file 'nodebb1/nodebb.bat'? yes
```

I must always put "yes" to all questions. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You may use force removing files:

```
rm -f -r nodebb1
```

instead of:

```
rm -r nodebb1
```

`-f`: Forcefully remove file.

`-r`: Remove the contents of directories recursively.

You may also check that file using another command/program.

```
lsoft | grep nodebb
```

Comment: I do your solution but I obtain: cannot remove 'nodebb': Device or resource busy